# Google maps markClusterer - syntax unclear

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I can't get Google maps clustering to work, having tried every example I've found. All the markers show, no console errors, but no clustering.

Firstly, I was having some problems with `markerClusterer not defined`, which sometimes happened, sometimes didn't. This clearly seemed to be the fact that my `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` script was set to `async` (my normal practice), meaning when the callback function I specified for it ran, `https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js` may not be loaded. It would be good to know if there's a way around this (a callback for the markerClusterer code?) but for now, to be clear about the real problem, I've removed `async`.

Since all the markers are working fine I'll only give the code relevant to clustering. In the callback function to init the map I've tried this approach (adding the markers to an array, then giving the whole array to `markerClusterer`):

```
var marker;
var markers = [];

for ( var member_id in members_data ) {

    // Add marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: members_data[ member_id ].location_data.lat,
            lng: members_data[ member_id ].location_data.lng
        },
        map: my_map,
    });
    markers.push( marker );

}

const marker_clusterer = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ my_map, markers });
```

I've also found this syntax, where the markers are individually added:

```
var marker;
var markers          = [];
var marker_clusterer = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ my_map });

for ( var member_id in members_data ) {

    // Add marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: members_data[ member_id ].location_data.lat,
            lng: members_data[ member_id ].location_data.lng
        },
        map: my_map,
    });
    markers.push( marker );
    marker_clusterer.addMarker( marker );

}
```

Neither work - no console errors, no clustering, normal markers all fine. Any clues as to how I can even start to debug this?

Comment: The syntax `new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer` is not correct (should be (`new MarkerClusterer`), where do you see that documented?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, or see one of the duplicate questions.  There are examples of both adding an array of markers and adding individual markers to an existing MarkerClusterer in various posts on StackOverflow.

Comment: @geocodezip ``new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer`` is found on the offical Google docs page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering#adding-a-marker-clusterer

Comment: @geocodezip To be clear, as I said, I've spent a very long time scouring StackOverflow trying all the examples, none work. The above two seem to be the most commonly given. I'd appreciate it if anyone knows of other methods.

Comment: The `MarkerClusterer` constructor in the posted code is clearly wrong. I know there are working examples here (with mcve's)

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks, got a link?

Comment: I have a fix in for the documentation when using via NPM.

Comment: You could try these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1210329+MarkerClusterer

Comment: It also might be helpful to know which version of MarkerClusterer you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var marker_clusterer = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ my_map });
```

should be

```js
var marker_clusterer = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map: my_map });
```

Comment: Spot on, many thanks. In my defence, `const markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });` isn't 100% clear! But the answer is obvious in retrospect, given JS object syntax.